# Melhor maneira de montar uma classe para executar um package SQL

Tags: c#, sql, design-pattern, orm

Estou montando uma camada de acesso a banco e preciso acessar as funções dentro de um package no servidor oracle.

A orm já conecta no banco e acessa tabelas e procedures através de seus respectivos repositórios e entidades.

Pensei em criar uma classe de serviço com diversas classes de retorno e os métodos mapeando as funções, como no modelo abaixo:

```
public class RetornoMetodoA
{
    public string ValorA { get; set; }
    public int ValorB { get; set; }
}

public class RetornoMetodoB
{
    public string ValorA { get; set; }
}

public class PacoteSQLServico
{
    public RetornoMetodoA Funcao1(string parametro1)
    {
        var retorno = new RetornoMetodoA();
        //Acessa o banco e roda a função do package
        // exec PacoteSQLServico.Funcao1(parametro1)
        return retorno;
    }

    public RetornoMetodoB Funcao2(string parametro1, string parametro2)
    {
        var retorno = new RetornoMetodoB();
        //Acessa o banco e roda a função
        // exec PacoteSQLServico.Funcao2(parametro1, parametro2) 
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

Em termos de design de código, qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Está meio confusa a pergunta, sem inicio, meio e fim! poderia explicar melhor

Comment: Editei e tentei deixar mais claro minha dúvida que é em relação ao design do código

Comment: Tem que ver se isso é possivel, logo de cara procedure eu sei que dá! funções tem uma forma também, mas, é muito ampla seu questionamento por não focar em uma item. poderia criar a sua pergunta mediante um item uma função coisa do tipo e o que já tentou fazer!

Comment: Dá sim. Eu crio um comando oracle e faço a chamado com o "nomedopacote.nomedafuncao". A questão é qual o melhor design para montar esse pacote e não deixar tudo dentro de uma string.

Comment: Eu sei que até é possivel como já tinha relatado, agora é meio que no adivinha a sua pergunta, por não term um algo real, e se a sua pergunta é sobre opinião ela pode ser fechada, por ser baseada em opiniões entendeu. Porque não coloca na sua pergunta o exemplo feito?

Comment: Mas eu coloquei já o exemplo acima.

Comment: Se colocou um exemplo que ao meu ver não é a realidade da função que está no Oracle e no seu ORM, e nem disse qual é o ORM e como fez esse processo ... veja, falta muitos variaveis para responder seu questionamento. bom !

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66021/discussion-between-dipi-evil-and-virgilio-novic).